# Instance on Point - the cube instance looks "jagged"

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have very simple scene, Bezier curve that should mimic a trend line with points (the cube) at the chart data points.

I used Geometry Nodes to add a cube to every point of the curve but the cube instances look jagged, with many vertices instead of looking like a cube. I tried using smoothing, but it didn't work. I'm new to the Geometry Nodes and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Picture of the Nodes:
[image]

Picture of the problem:
[image]

Edit: Resolved by duplicating the curve and using the Geometry Nodes on the curve without the bevel applied.Thank you Duarte Farrajota Ramos, Gordon Brinkmann for your answers, it was of great help to me.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cube isn't jagged, what you see is likely multiple cubes overlapping.

If you look closely on your *Resample Curve* node there is an exclamation mark warning at the top, that tells you something is wrong. Without more info I'd wager if you hove your cursor over it, it will tell you something along the lines of "*Input geometry has Unsupported type: Mesh*".

My blind guess is you beveled you curve using *Object Data > Geometry > Bevel* curve parameters. On doing so, your object despite being a bezier curve no longer has curve data, and starts instead bearing mesh data representing the circular profile swept along the actual underlying bezier curve geometry.

With curve data gone what you see is now the cube instanced on the points of the mesh surface resulting from beveling the curve.

If you want to use geometry nodes on the curve you can't use the native bevel feature. You have to pass the pure unbeveled, unextruded curve data into the node tree and instance on points before beveling.

You can do so from the *Curve > Operations > Curve to Mesh* node after instancing.

Comment: +1 I'd say your blind guess is correct. Since there is nothing in the GN nodetree creating a curve with a profile swept along, it has to be like that.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann True, most likely, yes. There is also the remote possibility there is another geometry node modifier before this one doing other fancy things, but it is speculation at best

Comment: You were right. It was multiple cubes being shown overlapping because of the bevel that was applied with value of 0.03m. I have fixed the issue by using copy of the curve just a bevel and the original is used for the nodes.